# AngularJS NodeJS add $scope in external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a controller `controller.js` that returns `$scope.result = result;`

I have an other JavaScript file canvas.js and I would like to insert `$scope.result` data.

`canvas.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var d_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = d_canvas.getContext('2d');
    var background = document.getElementById('background');
    context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);


    context.rect(100, 50, 200, 20);
    context.rect(150, 205, 200, 20);
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.strokeStyle = 'green';
    context.stroke();

    // it doesn't display my data
    console.log("SCCOPE: "+$scope.idArticle);

});
```

I have the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
```

Comment: It is not possible to access $scope in non AngularJS context. You cannot do it this way!

Comment: Arf :( How can I process because my coordinates (canvas) are in $scope.result and I need to display it.

Comment: Can you give more details? Currently I think you can wrote a directive and move these code into `link` function. If you don't want to reuse, use controller and move this code into controller.

Comment: I have a picture and I want to draw with canvas some shapes. I got the cooordinates via $scope.result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines in your HTML

```
<canvas my-canvas coords={{result}}></canvas>
```

and then this directive

```
app.directive('myCanvas', function() {
   return {
     link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var context = elem.getContext('2d');
        var background = document.getElementById('background');
         context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
         [draw point at attrs.coords]
       }...
```